# Flutter google admob : adds are showing only for one day

Tags: flutter, admob, apk

I'm a beginner with Flutter.

I'm trying to show adds on my app (version 1.2.0). I've noticed that the adds are working well but only for one day. The next day I built the apk it stops working, building a new one will work until the next day. So I decided to upgrade to 4.0.0 and to add the SDK in build.gradle (hope it would solve the issue).
`dependencies { implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0' }`

When updraging the version and adding the code I have this error

```
C:/Users/USER/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.6.2/10f354fdb64868baecd67128560c5a0d6312c495/lifecycle-common-2.6.2.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

I've tried to update ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0' in android/build.gradle and run
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter gen-l10n
flutter build apk

But it gave me another error

```
Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                                                                          │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update C:\dev\my_project\android\build.gradle: │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'
```

The kotlin version i had when i create my project was '1.7.10'
I have this gradle version in build.gradle classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'

But my downloaded version is C:\Program Files\Gradle\gradle-7.6.3\bin

Here is my pubspec.yaml file

```yaml
name: name
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+2

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.3 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  json_theme: ^6.3.0
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: any
  firebase_auth: ^4.12.0
  firebase_core: ^2.17.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.9.3
  provider: ^6.0.5
  camera: ^0.10.5+5
  google_mlkit_text_recognition: ^0.10.0
  permission_handler: ^11.0.1
  collection: ^1.17.2
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-beta.2
  country_flags: ^2.1.1
  uuid: ^4.2.1
  google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.3


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/image/app_logo.png"

flutter:
  generate: true
  uses-material-design: true
```

I'm completely lost, any help would be appreciated. Maybe I can stay on the 1.2.0 version and my issue (adds stay only 1 day) will be solved when it's on the play store? The app will be soon in closed tests. The adds work fine as on the google admob console, it has already generated a few money with my personnal tests.